# linq function to handle : both fields equal or both null or empty

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Hi I have a linq query where I compare an object with all other entity stored in my database. Firstname and lastname are mandatory fields so I don't have to check for null. But in the case of street I have to do these checks.

I want to match if both fields are null or empty strings or that they are the same. The below linq query is working fine.

But I was wandering isn't there any way to make it more readable. For example with a custom function like **Bool FieldsAreEqualOrBothNullOrEmpty(r.street, request.street)**

Can't figure how to do that and if it's possible.

```
var same = 
   from r in db.Requests
   where r.firstName.ToLower() == request.firstName.ToLower()
      && r.lastName.ToLower() == request.lastName.ToLower()

      //Seems long to just compare two fields
      && ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.street) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.street) ) 
         || r.street.ToLower() == request.street.ToLower()

      select r;
return same;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simplify:

```
var same = 
   from r in db.Requests
   where r.firstName.ToLower() == request.firstName.ToLower()
      && r.lastName.ToLower() == request.lastName.ToLower()
   select r;

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.street)) {
    same = same.Where(r => string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.street));
} else {
    string street = request.street.ToLower();
    same = same.Where(r => r.street.ToLower() == street);
}
```

The nice thing about the this is that it keeps the query simple in each case.
You could use similar logic for the first two if you choose, and it *could* also be moved to an expression-based utility method. Untested:

```
public static IQueryable<T> FieldsAreEqualOrBothNullOrEmpty<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> member, string value)
{
    Expression body;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        body = Expression.Call(
            typeof(string), "IsNullOrEmpty", null, member.Body);
    }
    else
    {
        body = Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Call(member.Body, "ToLower", null),
            Expression.Constant(value.ToLower(), typeof(string)));
    }

    return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(
        body, member.Parameters));
}
```

then:

```
var same = db.Requests
           .FieldsAreEqualOrBothNullOrEmpty(x => x.firstName, request.firstName)
           .FieldsAreEqualOrBothNullOrEmpty(x => x.lastName, request.lastName)
           .FieldsAreEqualOrBothNullOrEmpty(x => x.street, request.street);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The expression based method was a first shot and it works perfectly !

Comment: I asked a question about this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315584/linq-express-to-handle-null  because I can't get it to work when there is a null in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) but ignore case, using an appropriate [StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx).

```
string.equals(r.street, request.street, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

It's bad practice to convert strings to lower-case for comparison purposes, as it won't reliably work in all languages, and is slower than using a comparison which ignores case. See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2433217/15393)

Comment: depends a bit on whether the handler (EF in this case) recognises that and can process it correctly; that varies per handler and per scenario.

Comment: This will not match the case where `r.street = null` && `request.street = ""`. For that you need something like: `(r.street ?? "").Equals(request.street ?? "", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: I tried this which seems the simplest way but my sql server database doesn't seem to support that because of the collation and it yields an exception.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti You're right, sorry. I'd misread the question, and hadn't realised he wanted to treat null and empty as the same.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating extension method on string `IsEqualOrBothNullOrEmpty` -

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static bool IsEqualOrBothNullOrEmpty(this string firstValue,
                           string secondValue)
   {
      return string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstValue) &&
               string.IsNullOrEmpty(secondValue)
                  || firstValue.ToLower() == secondValue.ToLower();
    }
}
```

And use in your query like this -

```
var same = 
   from r in db.Requests
   where r.firstName.ToLower() == request.firstName.ToLower()
      && r.lastName.ToLower() == request.lastName.ToLower()
      && r.street.IsEqualOrBothNullOrEmpty(request.Street)

      select r;
return same;
```

Comment: That will only work for LINQ-to-Objects. The question states (tags) Entity Framework. For that, you need to do expression re-writing.