# Linq Expression to handle null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use the following code in a linq expression, which I found at 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045303/linq-function-to-handle-both-fields-equal-or-both-null-or-empty)
However it fails if the database field is null.

```
  public static IQueryable<T> FieldsAreEqualOrBothNullOrEmpty<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> source,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> member,
        string value)
    {
        Expression body;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            body = Expression.Call(typeof(string), "IsNullOrEmpty", null, member.Body);
        }
        else
        {
            body = Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Call(member.Body, "ToLower", null),
                Expression.Constant(value.ToLower(), typeof(string)));
        }
        return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, member.Parameters));
    }
```

It looks to me as if the code

```
 Expression.Call(member.Body, "ToLower", null)
```

is the problem , but I don't know what to use in it's place.

Answer (score 5):

```
Expression.Call(member.Body, "ToLower", null)
```

should be replaced with

```
Expression.IfThenElse(
    Expression.Equals(member.Body, Expression.Constant(null)),
    Expression.Constant(null),
    Expression.Call(member.Body, "ToLower", null))
```

which translates to

```
body == null ? null : body.ToLower();
```

Comment: I get Argument type bool is not assignable to parameter type 'system.linq.Expressions.Expression'

Comment: Should it be Expression.Equal  not Expression.Equals ?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d260f631-cf76-4c7a-8305-903faf7f373b/nullable-types-in-expression-build?forum=linqprojectgeneral  has more information.