# "Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of upper function" when trying to add a third item to a filter

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have been following the Contoso University tutorial on the ASP.NET website. I am trying to expand my skills and so decided to try adding a third option to the filter. The tutorial provides:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                           || s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
}
```

Let's say I've got a third column called Nickname. I tried adding this to the filter by adding an additional || operator:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                           || s.FirstMidName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                           || s.Nickname.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
}
```

When I run with the third option added I get:

`[SqlException (0x80131904): Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of upper function.]`

What am I missing here? What do I need to learn next to help me understand more about what's happening here?

Comment: What are underlying types? I suppose they must be text/ntext?

Comment: Compare your SQL definition of Nickname and LastName columns.

Answer (score 2):

I recall having problems with NTEXT columns before when using Entity Framework. To get around this, I now only ever use NVARCHAR(MAX). I am not sure whether that would help in your situation.. whether you are able to change the db type or not... otherwise, there is further info here:

[Linq to Entities : using ToLower() on NText fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431908/linq-to-entities-using-tolower-on-ntext-fields)

Answer (score 1):

Try the link below.

http://johnnblade.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/sql-query-replace-error-argument-data-type-ntext-is-invalid-for-argument-1-of-replace-function/

You will have to cast the current text/ntext value as nvarchar(max).