# Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of lower function

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, lambda

In my application's search function, I have implemented a search function which executes the following statement against the database.

```
resultsquery = db.DBMovies.Where(m => (m.Actors.ToLower()).Contains(q.ToLower()))
```

In the part `q.ToLower()` I read the url parameter `q` and converts into lowercase and find it in the relevant database column. In my database, the column 'Actors' is of type 'text' rather than varchar. When I run my application, I get an exception called `Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of lower function`. Is there any way that I can avoid this exception? I prefer a way that I can solve it in a single line.

Thank you.

Comment: text is sql datatype for very large texts, it can hold up to 2GB; I sincerely doubt you'll need that for actor column of "Movie" table; you really should be using nvarchar(some reasonable limit) or nvarchar(max) if you're unreasonable - check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: text and ntext fields are for very large text data. You should use a varchar field. You can perform queries like that easier against varchar fields than text fields. For more info see: http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/why-do-i-get-argument-data-type-text-is-invalid-for-argument.html

Comment: check if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431908/linq-to-entities-using-tolower-on-ntext-fields

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar You are right! but isn't there a way to solve this without changing database?

Answer (score 8):

Just change the datatype of your column in database to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and your code will work like a charm. It's a known issue, if you do some googling. For instance please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364484/argument-data-type-ntext-is-invalid-for-argument-1-of-upper-function-when-tryi).

Comment: This worked for me as well. It would help others if OP marked this as the best answer.

Comment: If you can't change the datatype, use`convert(varchar(max), myValue)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert the column to a VARCHAR - Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE DBMovies
ALTER COLUMN Actors VARCHAR(MAX)
```