# Getting "Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function." on Contains() method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I was working on an entity framework project and I wanted to do a LINQ Where() clause that has a contains based on the string state of an entity passed in as an enum.

```
string strState = state.ToString(); //convert enum to string
var logs = await _context.DispatchChangeLogs.Where(x => x.NewValues.Contains(strState)).ToListAsync();
```

This returns the error:

> Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function.

In the above example, the strState value is "Approved". When I put "Approved" directly into the Contains method, it returns that set of values I am looking for with this query.

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684815/argument-data-type-text-is-invalid-for-argument-1-of-lower-function) that gives a good explanation on the issue.

I changed the NewValues type in the database to varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) as a test. I updated my VS database project and republished to my local database. The database shows it as nvarchar(max).

[image]

The target framework for the DB project is .Net Framework 4.5.2

Any thoughts on why this would still be returning that "data type text" error?

Comment: "This returns the error" - where, how? Is this a SQL error or a EF error?

Comment: I apologize for the late response. I believe the error is a SQL error, but I think it is caused by EF. I have tried changing it to several different BD types, all to no avail. I found a workaround, but still want to know what is causing this.

Comment: Argument 1 of `CHARINDEX` is the text to find, so in your case the value of `strState` is being converted into `text` type by EF for some reason. Can you capture/output the SQL for your query? I assume you are using EF 4.8?